# How to improve slow sql query with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show top ten customers,sales,margin where customers is registred during this accounting year. The query takes about 65seconds to run and it is not accepted :-( 
As you may see i am not good at sql and will be very happy for help to improve the query.

```
SELECT Top 10 
  AcTr.R3, Actor.Nm, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN AcTr.AcNo<='3999' THEN AcAm*-1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sales , 
  SUM(AcAm*-1) AS TB
FROM AcTr, Actor 
WHERE (Actor.CustNo = AcTr.R3) AND
      (Actor.CustNo <> '0') AND
      (Actor.CreDt >= '20180901') AND 
      (Actor.CreDt <= '20190430') AND 
      AcTr.AcYr = '2018' AND
      AcTr.AcPr <= '8' AND
      AcTr.AcNo>='3000' AND
      AcTr.AcNo <= '4999'
GROUP BY AcTr.R3, Actor.Nm 
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

Comment: Is everything really a textual datatype?

Comment: You can add your table to question

Comment: Could you please include the CREATE TABLE statements for both tables? It will help us understand how the tables are structured as well as the column types (which I believe may be contributing to some of the slowness here with implicit casting). Also, do you have access to create indexes on tables (or are you in a position to suggest indexes to a DBA)?

Comment: Query optimization questions should include the execution plan. Please add that to your question.

Comment: It is the SQL to our ERP ( Visma Business) so i dont have any CREATE TABLE statements or any possibilities to create indexes.

Comment: Will your users accept numbers that are a day old?  If so, you can run this query at night and store the data in a staging table, and then report from the staged data.

Comment: @Brian unfortunately not, must be at runtime. ( Belongs to a reporting dashboard with a lot of other info as well ).

Comment: What indexes do you have applied to your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community.  You have a good start, but future, it is more helpful if you can provide (as commented), the CREATE table declarations so users know the actual data types.  Not always required, but helps.

As for your query layout, it is more common to show the JOIN syntax instead of WHERE showing relations between tables, but that comes in time and practice.

Indexes help and should be based on a combination of both WHERE/JOIN criteria AND Grouping fields.  Also, if fields are numeric, then do not 'quote' them, just leave as numbers.  For example, your AcYr, AcPr, AcNo.  I would think that an account number really would be a string value vs number for accounting purposes.

I would suggest the following indexes on your tables

```
Table   Index
Actr    ( AcYr, AcPr, AcNo, R3 )
Actor   ( CustNo, CreDt )
```

The Actr table I have the filtering criteria first and the R3 last to help optimize the GROUP BY.  The Actor table by the customer number, then the CreDt (Create date??), and is it really a string, or is it a date field?  If so, the date criteria would be something like '2018-09-01' and '2019-04-30'

```
select TOP 10
        Actor.Nm,
        PreSum.Sales,
        PreSm.TB
    from
        ( select
                R3,
                SUM(CASE WHEN AcTr.AcNo <= '3999' 
                    THEN AcAm * -1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sales,
                SUM( AcAm * -1) AS TB
            from
                Actr
            where
                    AcTr.AcYr = 2018
                AND AcTr.AcPr <= 8
                AND AcTr.AcNo >= '3000' 
                AND AcTr.AcNo <= '4999'
            GROUP BY 
                AcTr.R3 ) PreSum
            JOIN Actor
                on PreSum.R3 = Actor.CustNo
                AND Actor.CustNo <> 0
                AND Actor.CreDt >= '20180901'
                AND Actor.CreDt <= '20190430'
    order by
        Sales DESC
```

Per latest inquiry / comment, wanting by year comparison and getting rid of the top 10 performers per a given time period.

```
select 
        Actor.Nm,
        PreSum.Sales2018,
        PreSum.Sales2019,
        PreSum.TB2018,
        PreSum.TB2019
    from
        ( select
            AcTr.R3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN AcTr.AcYr = 2018 
                        AND AcTr.AcNo <= '3999'
                    THEN AcAm * -1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sales2018,
            SUM(CASE WHEN AcTr.AcYr = 2019 AND AcTr.AcNo <= '3999' 
                    THEN AcAm * -1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sales2019,
            SUM( CASE WHEN AcTr.AcYr = 2018 
                    THEN AcAm * -1 else 0 end ) AS TB2018
            SUM( CASE WHEN AcTr.AcYr = 2019 
                    THEN AcAm * -1 else 0 end ) AS TB2019
            from
                Actr
            where
                    AcTr.AcYr IN ( 2018, 2019 )
                AND AcTr.AcPr <= 8
                AND AcTr.AcNo >= '3000' 
                AND AcTr.AcNo <= '4999'
            GROUP BY 
                AcTr.R3 ) PreSum
            JOIN Actor
                on PreSum.R3 = Actor.CustNo
                AND Actor.CustNo <> 0
                AND Actor.CreDt >= '20180901'
                AND Actor.CreDt <= '20190430'
    order by
        Sales DESC
```

Comment: Fantastic :-) I havent used any indexes but the query went from 65seconds to 0,5seconds... @DRapp -> Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Dear @DRapp. If i want to include several years and have them grouped by year. Is this possible to do in same query?

Comment: @MartinBergius, yes you can span years in same query, but the top 10 would only get whatever the first year was possibly, or extend it...  With such a fast query, might just be as easy running multiple times back-to-back per year range comparisons.  There are other ways, but much more complex. Also, what are you really trying to do... year-to-year comparison activity per account?

Comment: yes want to have last years figures for comparison. Lets say we remove top ten and get all  results from Two years back grouped by year?

Comment: @MartinBergius, see revised answer.  Left original, posted an additional query without the top 10, but look at the inner query, I added the additional year to be included and also the corresponding group by. You may still want to adjust whatever the "Actor.CreDt" range is (which I believe is when the account holders was actually created, but the YEAR filter is allowing for 2018 and 2019 activity.

Comment: Testing and i have been unclear in my question. Sorry for that. With the new query the response is several rows per customer.                                                                         My intention is to have one row per customer showing all on same row like CustNo Result 2019 TB1 2019 Result 2018 TB1 2018. Is that possible?

Comment: @MartinBergius, see revision with per-year on same row

Comment: Dear @DRapp, Thank you very much. Best Xmas gift in years. You are a star :-)